# Forbid users from accessing a long URL while allowing access to a shorter one with mod_rewrite

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to block the following URL:

```
www.example.com/Ayurveda/article/guna/alkalizing/contains/non-vegan/experience/relieves-burning
```

But I want to allow:

```
www.example.com/Ayurveda/article/guna/cold
```

I'm using the following code to match anything with 3 forward slashes after the word "article". The problem is that both of these URLs are returning "forbidden".

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*)Ayurveda/article/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$ [NC,OR] 
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `%{THE_REQUEST}` contains the full HTTP request header sent by the browser, not simply the URL. If you examine this value, you will see that for the second (short) URL, `THE_REQUEST` does in fact contain 3 forward slashes after the word "article" (although not necessarily part of the URL itself) and so matches the pattern. The request line is probably something like:

```
GET /Ayurveda/article/guna/cold HTTP/1.1
```

However, it will be much more efficient to specify the pattern in the `RewriteRule` instead, if possible. As it currently stands, `.*` will result in *every* request being processed by the ruleset.

So, maybe something like the following in .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^Ayurveda/article(/[^/]+){3,} - [F]
```

The `L` flag is implied when the `F` flag is used, so it is unnecessary.